# How to use SetInterval to change this State variable in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got this function that takes in a data set (JSON) and returns an object. But I want to be able to change this data set every 2 seconds. So I need to somehow change that argument every 2 seconds and then call it so a different object is rendered every two seconds

The Function:

```js
const [dataset, setDataSet] = useState(season19)


const stats = [{"stat" :"points" , ppg: ""}, {"stat": "rebounds", ast: ""}, {"stat": "assists", reb: ""}]

    const sortedData = (dataset, nums) => {
      const finalData = nums.map((stat) => {
           if(Object.values(stat).includes("points")){
               return{
                   ...stat,
                   ppg: dataset[0].pts
               }
           } else if(Object.values(stat).includes("rebounds")){
            return{
                ...stat,
                reb:dataset[0].reb
            }
           } else if(Object.values(stat).includes("assists")){
               return{
                   ...stat,
                   ast:dataset[0].ast
               }
           }
        
       }) 
        return finalData
       
    }
```

and im calling it like so:

```
sortedData(dataset,stats)
```

The other two data sets are season20 and season21

How would I approach this?

**What I tried**

I put this into the sortedData function ,

```
 setInterval(() => {
        setDataset(season20)
      }, 2000)
```

it works but obviously it only changes to season20, how can I do it so it changes to season21 also